# Difference between @Autowired final setter and non-final setter in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, spring-aop

Assuming:

```java
    abstract class CommonService {

        protected VipMapper vipMapper;

        @Autowired
        public final void setVipMapper(VipMapper vipMapper) {
            this.vipMapper = vipMapper;
        }
    }

    @Service
    public class BookService extends CommonService {

        public int find() {
            return vipMapper.findVip(); // return 100
        }
    }

    @SpringBootTest
    class BookServiceTest {

        @Autowired
        private BookService bookService;

        @Test
        void find() {

            VipMapper v = new VipMapper() {
                @Override
                public int findVip() { // This method will not execute
                    return 10;
                }
            };

            bookService.setVipMapper(v);
            int find = bookService.find(); // find = 100 (not 10)
        }
    }
```

**1.** What is the reason I cannot inject  `VipMapper` when `setVipMapper` method is `final` and I can inject when `setVipMapper` method is not `final`?

**2.** How can I inject `VipMapper` in runtime but still use `@Autowired` `final` setter?

**Update**

I'm using `Spring` + `Mybatis`

Source code:
https://bitbucket.org/nguyentanh/stackoverflow

Using the above code, when run that test for `findVipCustomerTop3`, I get an error connection. But when to remove **final** in `CommonService.java` (or `@Transactional` in `BookService.java`), the test is success

Comment: could not replicate with JDK 11 / Spring boot '2.2.5.RELEASE' ;  test passes for 10 ; share the same from your test / create simple project to demo.

Comment: @PrasadU: could you please check my source code? Thanks.

Comment: @nguyen-tanh, please ask one question per post and it is the recommended practice. It allows any discussion to be focused on that question alone. And also there can be multiple answers which all can be correct each addressing a different concern and it will be problematic for any future users as only one answer is marked as accepted. It is also one of the criteria to `flag` your post (the option under your post). If your question get flagged, it is not from me but I just wanted point the best practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You issue is not with autowiring. `VipMapper` get autowired correctly and you are trying to replace the mapper manually via `bookService.setVipMapper(v);` in your test. It does not replace the `vipMapper` you passed. To Check this behaviour, define a getter in your service to get the `vipMapper` and it will return the original `vipMapper` which was autowired by spring.
- Just remember you are not working with an instance of your original `BookService` class, you are working with a sub class of `BookService` which is run time generated .
- Your original question missed an important piece of info which is  `@Transactional` annotation in your service. As soon as  `@Transactional` annotation is there, Spring actually need to create a proxy. Now spring will choose `JDK dynamic proxy` or `CGLIB proxy` to create the proxy for your book service. Since your Service does not have an interface, JDK dynamic proxy choice is not possible so spring is left with CGLIB proxy.
- CGLIB proxy has its limitations.

  > With CGLIB, final methods cannot be advised, as they cannot be overridden in runtime-generated subclasses
- Here is technique if you want to actually replace it. Add the following in your test class instead of the line `bookService.setVipMapper(v);`

```
    ((BookService)AopProxyUtils.getSingletonTarget(bookService))
                  .setVipMapper(v);
```

- The above option is doing it hardcore way but good for understanding the concept. There is another option telling spring to create `BookService` in your test with a mock `vipMapper` autowired when it creates `BookService`.

```
     @SpringBootTest
     class BookServiceTest {

        @Autowired
        private BookService bookService;
        
        @MockBean
        private VipMapper vipMapper;

        @Test
        void find() {
            when(vipMapper.findVip()).thenReturn(10);
            bookService.setVipMapper(v);
            int find = bookService.find();
        }
    }
```

**Reference**

- https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.8.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-proxying

Comment: You're great. Thank you!

Comment: See the last option in the updated answer too and is same as `@doctore`s last option but with `@MockBean`

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you are using @autowired for setVipMapper() so it already injected VipMapper with default findVip() returing 100. Therefore, defining setVipMapper() as final won't change the value you pass through anymore